# TileService not working, tile becomes unresponsive

Tags: android, service, altbeacon, foreground-service

I've made a tileService which triggers a foreground service when clicked. I have taken the battery optimisation permission from settings and set it on don't optimise. However after 3 days the tile becomes unresponsive.

```
public class QSIntentService
    extends TileService {

String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
Context context;
boolean isTileActive;


@Override
public void onStartListening() {
    super.onStartListening();
    Log.e(TAG, "-----onStartListening Tile--");
    if (isServiceRunning(getApplicationContext())) {
        isTileActive = true;
        updateTile();
    } else {
        isTileActive = false;
        updateTile();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick() {
    context = getApplicationContext();
    Log.e(TAG, "-----onClick --- ");

    Tile tile = getQsTile();
    isTileActive = (tile.getState() == Tile.STATE_ACTIVE);

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, 
ForegroundService.class);
    if (isServiceRunning(context)) {
        isTileActive = false;
        Utils.setBooleanFromPref(context, 
context.getString(R.string.widgetStop), true);
        if (ShareIBeaconInfo.INSTANCE.getForegroundService() != null) {
            ForegroundService foregroundService = 
ShareIBeaconInfo.INSTANCE.getForegroundService();
            if (foregroundService.scanDevice != null) {
                foregroundService.stopForegroundService();
            }
        }

        context.stopService(serviceIntent);
    } else {
        isTileActive = true;
        Utils.setBooleanFromPref(context, 
context.getString(R.string.widgetStop), false);
        Log.e(TAG, "service is not running");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Intent service = new Intent(context, 
ForegroundService.class);
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, service);
        } else {
            Intent service = new Intent(context, ForegroundService.class);
            context.startService(service);
        }
    }
    updateTile();
}


private void updateTile() {
    Tile tile = super.getQsTile();
    int activeState = isTileActive ?
            Tile.STATE_ACTIVE : Tile.STATE_INACTIVE;

    tile.setState(activeState);
    tile.updateTile();
}

private boolean isServiceRunning(Context context) {
    try {
        final ActivityManager manager;
        manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager
                .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if ("com.foregroundscan.service.ForegroundService"
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

My test device is OnePlus 6T running over android 9. Also is there a way to push a dialogue if the tile is unresponsive? So that I can restart the service?

I received a log when I click on a tile when it is unresponsive

```
2-08 16:34:56.710 1831-2154/? E/MdmLogger: Cannot get tag from tileTag 
: Tile.CustomTile
```

Comment: Do you see your other debug lines when the time becomes visible?  If you remove the foreground service start from your TileService, does this problem go away?

Comment: @davidgyoung I think these are the only lines relevant, but I'll try to get the whole log. The problem is making me curious as I started testing on 2 devices Oneplus 6 and Oneplus 6t both having same configs almost but the tile is working on Oneplus 6t even now. Also don't you think without a foreground service my beacons scanning could be killed any second and thus become unreliable? But I'll try anyways thanks

Comment: Yes, removing the foreground service may cause other problems, but the test may indicate if the freezing tile is caused by the foreground service or unrelated to it.

Comment: @davidgyoung The results remain the same even with a background service. Do you think it might be because after a while the OS does not have an instance of the app?

Comment: I doubt the issue is that there is no app.  I suspect something in the OS state is preventing the onClick event from getting called at all, which is why you don't see your log line inside of there.  I would suggest as a next step you start from scratch with the simplest possible TileService (using reference code) and verify it does not have this problem.  Then slowly modify it to add your functionality until it breaks.  The last thing you added before it breaks will give you a clue to what is going on.  This will be frustratingly time consuming, I know!

Comment: You may also try to whitelist your app from background/battery optimizations.  You may find that OnePlus breaks all TileService instances implemented by apps that are not whitelisted against battery optimizations.

Comment: I'm also having this issue on Oneplus 8T. I think it is not related to foreground service because I'm not using anything related to foreground service.